# python pandas organizing multidimensional data into an object

Tags: python, pandas

Having historical data from a stock exchange, with a number of stocks, and a number of a given stock's attributes (open, high, low, close, volume), I end up effectively having 3 dimensions in my data, i.e., `time stamp`, `stock's ticker` and the `attributes`. For a single stock (2D), I'd create one `pd.DataFrame`, but how should I go (efficiently and generically) about putting such data for many stocks into a single object? Is `pd.DataFrame` with multi-indexing the best possible solution?

Comment: i use a panel for similar types of analysis, http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html#panel, you can convert a 2-level from to a panel with to_panel (though usually easier to construct directly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you use a [Panel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html#panel), for example:

```
>>> from pandas.io.data import DataReader
>>> from pandas import Panel, DataFrame

>>> symbols = ['AAPL', 'GLD', 'SPX', 'MCD']
>>> data = dict((symbol, DataReader(symbol, "yahoo", pause=1)) for symbol in symbols)
>>> panel = Panel(data).swapaxes('items', 'minor')
>>> closing = panel['Close'].dropna()
>>> closing.head()

             AAPL    GLD     MCD     SPX
Date                
2010-01-04   214.01  109.80  62.78   1132.99
2010-01-05   214.38  109.70  62.30   1136.52
2010-01-06   210.97  111.51  61.45   1137.14
2010-01-07   210.58  110.82  61.90   1141.69
2010-01-08   211.98  111.37  61.84   1144.98
```

If you want to see more take a look at [this](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/5338034) example I made for a course.